# How to make importxml only give a certain data

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am trying to get only the number of likes from a website. Currently, I am using

```
=IMPORTXML("https://www.abillionveg.com/articles/vegan-diet-nutrition-guide","//button")
```

However, it gives me data from all of the buttons. Can someone help me modify the formula to show only the likes?
Sorry if this is a basic question, I am just learning.

Answer (score 1):

You want to retrieve the number of `the number of likes` using `IMPORTXML`.

If my understanding is correct, how about this answer?

#### Modified formula 1:

```
=INDEX(SPLIT(IMPORTXML(A1,"//div[@class='ArticleActions__Container-sc-15ye7g8-0 huWdyg'][1]//span[contains(text(),'likes')]")," "),1)
```

- The URL of `https://www.abillionveg.com/articles/vegan-diet-nutrition-guide` is put in the cell "A1".
- The xpath is `//div[@class='ArticleActions__Container-sc-15ye7g8-0 huWdyg'][1]//span[contains(text(),'likes')]`.
- Retrieve the value using `IMPORTXML`.
- Retrieve the number of `###` from the value like `### likes` using `SPLIT` and `INDEX`.

##### Result:

[image]

#### Modified formula 2:

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(IMPORTXML(A1,"//script[@id='__NEXT_DATA__']"),"likesCount""\:(\d+)") - 1
```

- This result is the same with Modified formula 1.

#### Note:

- For example, if `=IMPORTXML(A1,"//div[@class='ArticleActions__Container-sc-15ye7g8-0 huWdyg'][1]//span[contains(text(),'likes')]")` is used, `100 likes` is retrieved.

#### References

- [IMPORTXML](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093342)
- [SPLIT](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094136)
- [INDEX](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098242)